# Luis Entity recognized, but not returned

Tags: bots, azure-language-understanding

Within my LUIS model, I have a hierarchy entity type.  When I use the test console, it is recognized as Parent::Child.

However, when I make the rest call, I only receive the Parent.

I have verified that the active model is published to staging and that I am calling against the staging server.

Comment: did you republish the model after latest change of the definition?

Comment: I had published it twice before. Just tried again, and seems to be working.

Is this a known issue to occur? or just a fluke, and try to "reboot" kind of thing.

Comment: In general we use "publish twice" approach when using the UI - to be safer you may try REST API: "*/luis/api/v2.0/apps/{appId}/publish"